# how do i do php redirection after form and script?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I have this form and the user can choose things from a list. For the selected items the attribute in the database changes (Insert/Update statements). When the user clicks on the button the functions all work fine.

Now i want to redirect the user to another page after script. At the moment, the user can't see a difference after a click on the button, even though the script works fine.
This is the relevant part of the script:

```
 <div id="refresh-section">
            <form id="chk-input" role="form" method="post">
                <?php
                $vertragFS = $vertrag->getVertragFS($et);
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        <button id="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" form="refresh section" name="status">Flurstücke an Vertrag koppeln</button>
        
        <script>
            var form = document.getElementById('chk-input');

            document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                var fskz = [];

                form.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(input) {
                    if (input.type === 'checkbox' && input.checked) {
                        fskz.push(input.value);
                    }
                })
                string_json = JSON.stringify(fskz);
                //console.log(fskz);
                $.ajax({
                    method: "post",
                    data: {
                        fskz: JSON.stringify(fskz),
                    }
                })
                
            })
            

            <?php
            $fskz = json_decode($_POST['fskz'], true);
            $vid = $_GET['vid'];

            foreach ($fskz as $fkz) {
                $vertrag->insertVertragID($fkz, $vid);
                $vertrag->updateFlstStatusSN2($fkz);
            }
            

            ?>
        </script>
```

I already tried the 'standard things'. A header won't work due to the outputs. I also tried to run the script without the echo and console log statements, but it doesn't work.

A JS relocation reacts instantly, so the user cannot interact. Ob_start() and Ob_flush() haven't worked yet, I tried in combination with header at different lines in the script. Doesn't work.

I also tried to add a condition to the foreach statement, that user should get redirected after the last insert/update statement is executed. This doesn't work.

Can you give me advise what i need to look for or what i have to change in general? Thanks :)

Edit: I know i can add an extra button to relocate, but i want to combine it in the one existing button.

Comment: Welcome to SO! From your code, it looks like you don't have a good grasp of how PHP is supposed to work; typically you wouldn't BOTH output the `<form>` HTML **and** process the POST data in the same script.

Comment: Just drop the ajax call completely, use a form action attribute to redirect the user to a php page that processes the form, and then redirect the user to the new page from THAT script. Redirecting the user after an ajax request defeats the purpose of ajax requests. You don't actually need _any_ javascript to process this form.

Comment: @amphetamachine `typically you wouldn't BOTH output the <form> HTML and process the POST data in the same script`...people do that all the time, it's a very standard approach (if you're not using an MVC framework or something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AJAX probably doesn't make much sense if you want to redirect afterwards. While it's possible to do that, it misses the point of using AJAX, which is to avoid any need for postbacks / redirects etc.

You can achieve all this easily with a standard postback and sensible code structure.

If you put the code which processes the form and performs the redirect *first* in your script (within a check to see if the request is a POST, which is lacking in your code now) you can

- avoid the "headers already sent" issue when redirecting, because when the form is posted back this will be the first code to execute, meaning there's been no other output previously
- optionally allow the form to still show if there were validation errors, and be ready to put those errors onto the page near (or in) the form.

That is a very standard structure to use in a web application.

So something like this:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{
  /*code to process the submitted form fields (I can't see their names or structure so it's hard to write the correct commands) and submit the data
    ...
  */

  //redirect
  header("Location: someFile.php");
  exit();
 
}
?>

<div id="refresh-section">
  <form id="chk-input" role="form" method="post">
    <?php
      $vertragFS = $vertrag->getVertragFS($et);
    ?>
    <button id="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="status">Flurstücke an Vertrag koppeln</button>  
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this is helpful for anyone. This works perfectly for me. That's the part of the if condition: `     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

        // submitted form fields
        $fskz = $_POST['fskz'];


        foreach ($fskz as $fkz) {
            $vertrag->insertVertragID($fkz, $vid);
            $vertrag->updateFlstStatusSN2($fkz);
        }

        //redirect
        header("Location: ./person.php?et=$et&pbez=$pbez&bl=$bl");
        exit();
    } `

Answer (score -1):

Add ajax succes function, and then your php code should run after it. Then finally in the end you can redirect using js.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "post",
    data: {
        fskz: JSON.stringify(fskz),
    },
    success: function(response) {

        <?php
            $fskz = json_decode($_POST['fskz'], true);
            $vid = $_GET['vid'];

            foreach ($fskz as $fkz) {
                $vertrag->insertVertragID($fkz, $vid);
                $vertrag->updateFlstStatusSN2($fkz);
            }
        ?>

        // Handle success, then redirect
        window.location.href = 'your_destination_page.php'; // Change to the desired URL
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // Handle error, if needed
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Reloading the page after an ajax request kind of defeats the purpose of using an ajax request